# What is the biggest structure in nature for structural coloration?

Tags: physiology, anatomy, structural-biology, pigmentation

I'm interested in the actual sizes behind structural coloration: I find it fascinating and I think it may have a couple very nice applications.

The problem is I couldn't find anything but vague references about the actual structures' dimensions. Like, the thickness of the walls, their diameter, the height...

I'm sorry about the tags but I couldn't find anything fitting. Is this, like the wrong stackexchange section?

Edit: For what I mean by structural coloration please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_coloration.

> Structural coloration[a] is the production of colour by microscopically structured surfaces fine enough to interfere with visible light, sometimes in combination with pigments. For example, peacock tail feathers are pigmented brown, but their microscopic structure makes them also reflect blue, turquoise, and green light, and they are often iridescent.

Comment: You should define what you mean by "structural coloration", because with just the information in the question you could be talking about house paint. .